# bash variable with quotes and percentage

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

I want to use a time command in a script and put it into a variable (I will have to use it for many commands) so than I can modify just the single variable.

Simplified, this is how I tried it:

```
PROFILING="/usr/bin/time -f 'time: %e - cpu: %P'" ; $PROFILING ls /usr
```

I would expect that to be translated into:

```
# /usr/bin/time -f 'time: %e - cpu: %P' ls /usr
bin  games  include  lib  local  sbin  share  src
time: 0.00 - cpu: 0%
```

However I get this:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run %e: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
'time:
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word splitting doesn't understand quotes in the expanded variables. Use an array instead:

```
profiling=(/usr/bin/time -f 'time: %e - cpu: %P')
"${profiling[@]}" ls /usr
```

Or `alias`:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases # needed in scripts
alias profiling="/usr/bin/time -f 'time: %e - cpu: %P'"
profiling ls /usr
```

Or function:

```
profiling() { /usr/bin/time -f 'time: %e - cpu: %P' "$@"; }
profiling ls /usr
```